# What is the most efficient way to prevent reverse polarity to an opAmp?

Tags: power, operational-amplifier, safety

[image]

Above is a part of a circuit which is a Schmitt trigger.
As you see 24V DC Vcc and Gnd are the power rails.

I will set up this circuit and some other people are going to hook up input output and power connections each time they need.

My concern is, if someone connects the power connections reverse. 
I mean if one connects the power supply's plus to Gnd of this comparator and similarly power supply's minus to Vcc of this comparator, the circuit might damage because of the reverse DC voltage.

What could be the safety solution to eliminate a possible human mistake. I thought a diode connected on Gnd rail of the comparator might work.
But Im not sure about the voltage stability of the comparator if I use that.

What is the most efficient way to prevent reverse power connections to an opAmp?

A figure or a diagram illustration would help.

Comment: Use a polarized connector.

Answer (score 2):

A series diode on the +24 would help. Putting a diode in the ground can cause more problems with external signals. Right now your comparator switches at about 11.75/12.27V. With the diode it would switch at more like 11.45/11.97V, so not much different.

You might also want to protect any other inputs and outputs against connections in any possible combination.

Answer (score 0):

Since the comparator is working form a virtual ground, a practical approach is to simply use a bridge rectifier, making the power input polarity agnostic.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbd3nW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

THis is NOT the most **efficient** method - it burns two diode drops, and there are more efficient schemes using MOSFETs or the like, or some logic and a relay.

Where the loss of ~1.4V from the power rails is not a big issue, it's simple and robust.

Comment: What is In1 In2 in your diagram?

Comment: I though a single diode would work :(

Comment: Where your "users" connect the input power.

Comment: They will have.a 24V DC power supply and with crocodiles they will hook up to opamp rails

Comment: No, they connect to the input of the bridge. The opamp rails should not be exposed to them, if you are concerned with polarity reversal - the only terminals that they should have access to for power connection would be the inputs to the bridge - and then it does not matter how they connect those. Of course, some will find another method to break things, such as applying a power connection where a signal should go, but that's how users are...alternatively, chop off the crocodile clips and install a polarized power connector on the supply and the circuit.

Comment: What is In1 and In2?

Comment: I think IN1 and IN2 are power-supply connection points. The idea is that you can connect power either way around and the circuit will be powered correctly. If your circuit relies on having the GND rail at the same potential as the power supply 0 V then this circuit won't work as there is a diode between them.